# Rstudio - corrplot highlight ony high correlation values in the plot

Tags: r, plot, correlation, pearson-correlation, r-corrplot

I'm trying to highlight only correlation values <-.7 and >0.7 in my correlation plot, but I'm getting trouble on it.
I have this data like this
[Parn_Spt_comp_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csumH.png)

And I did a Pearson correlation with this code:

```
par_spt.pearson2 <-cor(Parn_Spt_comp_2[,3:14], method = "pearson")
par_spt.pearson2
```

After I plotted the values with the code below:

```
corrplot(par_spt.pearson2, method="color", addCoef.col = "black" ,type="lower", sig.level = 0.05,
         number.cex = 1.2, tl.col = "black",tl.cex = 1.25, number.font = 1, tl.srt = 0, tl.offset = 0.3, pch=19, addgrid.col="black",col=colorRampPalette(c("white","coral3"))(10), cl.cex=1.25, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
```

And display it:

[image: Correlation plot]

But I would like to show only correlation values in the interval mentioned above, and the values >-0.7 and <0.7 do not appear in the plot. I tried many things, but it still not working. I would be grateful if you help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should post _Parn_Spt_comp_2_ as text, not image.